# Consultar productos por categoría y mostrar todas sus categorías de cada producto obtenido

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla de productos que contiene los siguientes campos:
**id_curso, curso**.

```
| id_curso    |     curso                |
|-------------|--------------------------|
|     1       | Algebra                  |
|     2       | fisica cuantica          |
|     3       | Calculo                  |
|     4       | Probabilidad             |
|     5       | Ciencias naturales       |
|     6       | sistemas operativos      |
|     7       | Ciencias computacionales |
|-------------|--------------------------|
```

y otra tabla de categorías:
**id_categoria, categoria**,

```
| id_categoria | categoria        |
|--------------|------------------|
|      1       | matematicas      |
|      2       | ciencias         |
|      3       | informatica      |
|--------------|------------------|
```

y la ultima para relacionarlas:
**id, id_producto, id_categoría**.

```
| id | id_curso     | id_categoria     |
|----|--------------|------------------|
| 1  |      1       | 1                |
| 2  |      2       | 1                |
| 3  |      2       | 2                |
| 4  |      3       | 1                |
| 5  |      4       | 1                |
| 6  |      5       | 2                |
| 7  |      6       | 3                |
| 8  |      7       | 1                |
| 9  |      7       | 3                |
|----|--------------|------------------|
```

Lo que quiero es buscar por categoría y obtener todos los productos que tengan dicha categoría, pero tambien obtener todas las categorías a la que pertenece dicho producto.

Por ejemplo; obtengo dos categorías de entrada, **ciencias e informatica**; el resultado de la tabla sería algo tal que así:

```
| id_curso | id_categoria | curso                    | categoría   |
|----------|--------------|--------------------------|-------------|
|      2   | 1            | fisica cuantica          | matematicas |
|      2   | 2            | fisica cuantica          | ciencias    |
|      5   | 2            | Ciencias naturales       | ciencias    |
|      6   | 3            | sistemas operativos      | informatica |
|      7   | 1            | Ciencias computacionales | matematicas |
|      7   | 3            | Ciencias computacionales | informatica |
|----------|--------------|--------------------------|-------------|
```

Chequese que el curso *fisica cuantica* tiene la categoría *matematicas*, sin embargo no fue una categoría seleccionada, pero el curso posee dicha categoría junto a *ciencias* por ende ha sido traída.

Algo similar a la busqueda por etiquetas de Stackoverflow, en la cual puedes seleccionar varias etiquetas y los resultados tienen en la parte inferior más etiquetas.

Comment: ¿Ya intentaste algo?, te puede servir este [articulo](https://www.vichaunter.org/desarrollo-web/joins-mysql-bien-explicado-lo-necesitas-saber)

Comment: Por favor muéstranos el script que has intentado y especifica en que partes crees que te falla. Ya hiciste el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)?

Comment: Estoy utilizando nodejs en back y traté de traer todos los cursos de la misma categiría; con un `select * from cursos
INNER JOIN cursos_categorías ON cursos_categorias.id_curso = cursos.id
INNER JOIN categorias ON categorias.id = cursos_categorias.id_categoria
WHERE categorias = 'matematicas';`. Obtengo una lista y luego los recorro con un bucle, por cada curso busco sus categorías tal que así: `select * from cursos
INNER JOIN cursos_categorías ON cursos_categorias.id_curso = cursos.id
INNER JOIN categorias ON categorias.id = cursos_categorias.id_categoria
WHERE cursos.id = [id_curso];`

Comment: Pero este metodo tarda demasiado cuando son muchos registros

Comment: falta que nos digas los nombres de las tablas pero los invento. "SELECT TablaCurso.curso, TablaCategoria.categoria FROM TablaCategoria, TablaCurso, TablaRelaciones WHERE TablaRelaciones.id_curso = TablaCurso.id_curso AND TablaRelaciones = TablaCategoria.id_categoria AND TablaRelaciones = 'aca va el ID que quieras';" igualmente nose de donde salen esos ID en la ultima tabla, pero fijate si es por ahi tu objetivo.

Comment: Esta es mi consulta
`SELECT
 cursos.id_curso,
    cursos.curso,
    categorias_2.id_categoria,
    categorias_2.categoria
FROM cursos
INNER JOIN cursos_categorias ON cursos_categorias.id_curso = cursos.id_curso
INNER JOIN categorias ON categorias.id_categoria = cursos_categorias.id_categoria
INNER JOIN cursos_categorias as cursos_categorias_2 ON cursos_categorias.id_curso = cursos_categorias_2.id_curso
INNER JOIN categorias as categorias_2 ON categorias_2.id_categoria = cursos_categorias_2.id_categoria
WHERE categorias.categoria = "Matematicas" order by cursos.nombre_curso;`

Comment: A veces me trae unos registros correctos y a veces no lo hace